# "I had to ..." but "I haven't had to ..."

Tags: obligation

I've heard a sentence like this:
"I had to go to the doctor" for an obligation in the past.
I would have expected:
"I hadn't to go to the doctor" for the negative form, but I heard:
"I haven't had to go to the doctor"
why?
Best

Comment: "I haven't had to ..." is the negative form of "I have had to ..." The negative of "I had to ..." is "I didn't have to."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I  had  to  go  to  the  doctor** yesterday/ today.(past  obligation)

I  think the  opposite of  the  sentence is:

> **I did not  have  to  go to  the  doctor**

I  haven't had  to  go to  the  doctor  is  the  opposite  of  I have had to go to  the doctor which  can not  be  used  to  talk  about  past  abverbials  like  yesterday.

I think  you  may say  I  have n' t  had to  go to  the  doctor today or  I  didn't  have  to  go to  the  doctor  today..

But  in the  sentence  given  the  time  adverbial  is  not  specific